# Android - Cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, android-intent, static, final

Assume ClassA that define a static final string:

```
public class ClassA implements Serializable {

public final static String KeyString = "aKeyString";
```

And now ClassB trying to use this string:

```
anIntent.putExtra(ClassA.KeyString, anObject);
```

I get an error on the `ClassA.KeyString` part stating it cannot be resolved or is not a field. If I replace it with the string "aKeyString", it works fine. But I want to have a fixed key string to minimize typo erros.

Comment: Did you import ClassA ? Obviously, it should work ...

Comment: Yes, I import it and Eclipse shows that by making the KeyString italic.

Comment: Is the constant accessible from another class ?

Comment: Post your `activity.xml` and full java code .

Comment: On another thought is `class B` an abstract class ?

Comment: This a lot, I cannot continue with Eclipse. I simply restarted Eclipse and it works fine now. Does any of you suffer from this too?

Comment: Check if Build Automatically is checked in "Project" menu ...